# Android firebase: send push notification to paid users only

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am totally new to firebase cloud messaging. how am i suppose to send notifications to specific users such as paid users and free users. i have paid users stored in shared preferences. how to target only paid users ?

i just made this class:

```
public class MyMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

    }
    public  void showNotification(String title,String message){
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"MyNotifications")
                .setContentTitle(title)
             //   .setSmallIcon(androidx.work.R.drawable.)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentText(message);

        NotificationManagerCompat manager= NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        manager.notify(999,builder.build());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. FCM is initialized by each device and the Online Service assigns an ID to your App Instance (if you reinstall it this ID will change).
2. your App should comunicate the current UserID and this AppID above to your Server (PHP, Rails, .NET, Java or whatever you have)
3. the Server needs to check if UserID is one of Paid or not
4. the Server should store the relation between UserID and AppID
5. the Server can send a Notification to that specific AppID (at this time the Server knows which AppID use thanks to UserID and previous stored relationship)